# How do I convert a Django session to the new format?

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

We are using Django 3.0 for our websites, and I want to upgrade to Django 3.1 next month. I understand that the sessions format changed in Django 3.1, and that old sessions will be removed in Django 4.0 ([see documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#default-hashing-algorithm-settings)). I want to convert user sessions of users who will visit the site with Django 3.1 and 3.2 to the new session format, before I upgrade eventually to Django 4.0. How do I convert sessions to the new session format? I have to identify that these users are using the old session format, and then convert them (create a new session cookie for them with the new session format). Will it be done automatically by Django, or do I have to do it myself manually?

Comment: *(This may be rude, but )* AFAIK, if the sessions didn't match, Django asks the user to login again. Also, the [`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE) has a default value of *2 weeks*, which indicates that, your users need to login in every 2 weeks. (correct me if I am wrong). So, I don't think you need to write a script or a *method* to convert the session format in this case. Let the user login again.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` is set in our project to ~30 years, and I want to keep the users logged in. I don't want users to have to login again every 2 weeks.

Comment: For security reasons you should to close all 'old' sessions and force users to sign in, after migration, with the new algorithm. Just one time, not every 2 weeks.

Comment: @daniherrera And what is the security problem if I convert their sessions to the new format without forcing them to login again?

Comment: Now I understand your question, it has sense.